# PlotLegends is obsolete in v10?

Tags: plotting, legending

I am using Mathematica 10.0.2.0 on a Mac OS X (Yosemite v. 10.10.1, 64bit).

After I call:

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
```

I get the info:

***General::obspkg: PlotLegends` is now obsolete. The legacy version being loaded may conflict with current functionality. See the Compatibility Guide for updating information.***

What is meant by: "PlotLegends` is now obsolete"?

All the PlotLegends related keyword are nevertheless working.

Comment: I think it only means that you DONT have to load it separately. It's now automatically loaded. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html  They will work just fine without `Needs["PlotLegends`"]`.

Comment: I left Needs["PlotLegends`"] out, but in ListLinePlot I get then "Unknown option PlotLegend, LegendPosition, LegendSize, etc.", Hmmm ...

Comment: See: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/PlotLegends/ref/LegendSize.html

Answer (score 12):

You should use built-in option [`PlotLegends`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotLegends.html) now (note the `s` in the end). From MathGroup [archive](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2012/Dec/msg00439.html):

> WRI forgot to change the documentation PlotLegends/guide/PlotLegendsPackage so as to say it's obsolete and to refer to the new PlotLegends built into the kernel.

Comment: The answer currently suggests that all the functionality in the ``PlotLegends` `` package can be recreated using the `PlotLegends` option. It seems to me that it is not possible to create reasonable legends for a `Show` of a `Plot` and a `ListPlot` using this option however. Is this correct? It would seem something like `Legended` is needed.